# How to set a mediaSubtype on a PHAsset created by the app

Tags: ios, swift, gallery, photo, phasset

I'm creating an app that is intended to output an image with a custom depth map. I've managed to do this after a little bit of fiddling and it works nicely. However, despite having both a depth map and a portrait matte effect, and despite my being able to load and use these successfully within my app, the asset still does not have the correct media subtype (`PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoDepthEffect`). This is important to me since I want to filter the user's gallery and display only those images which contain a depth effect, and the proper way to do that is to query the media subtype.

Does anyone know what has to be done to ensure this subtype is properly set? I cannot find a way to change it, and can only assume that the system infers it from the asset's auxiliary data.

Answer (score 0):

below code will show all the images taken from camera in portrait mode

```
func getImages(){
        let assetCollection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .smartAlbumDepthEffect, options: nil).firstObject!
            let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection, options: nil)
        result.enumerateObjects { (ph_asset, int, unsafe_mutable_pointer) in
            PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: ph_asset, options: nil, resultHandler: { (data, string, image_orientation, info) in
                self.imageData.append(data!)
                self.imageString.append(string!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a temp solution that works

I can't find any APIs to declare a depth photo as an active portrait subtype like the photos app does when you tap the Portrait button. So I created a temporary fix until I can find a solution.

When taking a photo, I flag my photos with photoDepthEffects by setting the originalFilename with my App identifier. Then in the reader, I grab all the assets and check if the PHAssets mediaSubtype is set to PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoDepthEffect. These are the ones in the Portraits folder. This is pretty fast.

If not found, I look to see if the photo has my originalFilename flag. Grabbing an assetResource is kind of slow, so I only check for the last 200 photos taken.

We should contact Apple tech support and see if there is a way to flag the photos into the portrait folder like the photos app does.

Comment: Yeah it's the awful speed that puts me off implementing a hack like this :(